# No se elimina evento con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Simple y sencillamente Javascript no me quiere eliminar el evento de un `<audio>`, ya hice todo lo que investigue en internet y nada funciona.

No se que tengo mal o porque Javascript no esta haciendo caso y ya estoy desesperado.

**JavaScript**

```
var reproduccion = false;

var sonido = document.querySelector("#sonido");
var btn = document.querySelector("#btnAgregar");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   sonido.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        reproducirAudioFinal(1);
   });
});

function reproducirAudioFinal(estado = "")
{
    if(reproduccion == false)
    {
      if(estado == 1)
        sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/ganaste.mp3");
      else
        sonido.setAttribute("src", "audio/perdiste.mp3");
    
      sonido.play();
      reproduccion = true;
    }
    else
    {
        sonido.pause();
        reproduccion = false;
    }
}

function eliminarEvento()
{
    sonido.removeEventListener("ended", function(){
        reproducirAudioFinal();
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="sonido"></audio>
<button type="button" id="btnAgregar">Agregar Evento</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" onClick="eliminarEvento();">Eliminar Evento</button>
```

Comment: Con la información que haz proporcionado no puedo reproducir el problema (chiste malo), pero puedo ver que en tu html tienes una "clase" btn y en tu querySelector intentas seleccionar un "Id" has probado cambiar eso?

Comment: @MarcosLopez ya agregue ese boton al html para que se pueda entender mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En síntesis tu tienes esto:

```
//agregar evento
sonido.addEventListener("ended", function(){
     reproducirAudioFinal(1);
});

//eliminar evento
sonido.removeEventListener("ended", function(){
    reproducirAudioFinal();
 })
```

Esto es incorrecto, las función que tu pasas en el `addEventListener` no es la misma que le pasas en el `removeEventListener` y no son la misma no porque falte el `1` en la última, no son la misma porque están almacenadas en espacio de memoria distintos.

Tienes que crear la función con un nombre

```
function nombredelafuncion(){
  reproducirAudioFinal(1);
}
//agregar evento
sonido.addEventListener("ended", nombredelafuncion);

//eliminar evento
sonido.removeEventListener("ended", nombredelafuncion);
```

O por otro lado, usar directamente a `reproducirAudioFinal`

```
//agregar evento
sonido.addEventListener("ended", reproducirAudioFinal);

//eliminar evento
sonido.removeEventListener("ended", reproducirAudioFinal);
```

En este caso, seguramente tienes que setear el valor default en 1

```
function reproducirAudioFinal(estado = 1)
{
  //etc
```