# ¿Por qué removeEventListener no elimina correctamente los eventos de click en un bucle for?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código en el que intento remover eventos 'click' de una serie de elementos usando removeEventListener, pero parece que no está funcionando correctamente. He usado un bucle for para recorrer los elementos y remover los eventos, pero aún así los eventos persisten. ¿Alguna idea de por qué esto podría estar sucediendo o cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
<section class="contenedor">
      <div id="marcador">Puntaje X:
        <p class="puntaje" id="puntajeX"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="marcador">puntaje O:
        <p class="puntaje" id="puntajeO"></p>
      </div>
      <table>
        <!--Primera fila -->
        <tr class="fila">
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          
        </tr>
      
        <!--segunda fila -->
        <tr class="fila">
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
        </tr>
        
        <!--tercera fila -->
        <tr class="fila">
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
          <td class="cuadro"></td>
        </tr>
        
      </table>
      
      <h2 id="Resultado"></h2>
      <button id="siguiente">siguiente</button>
    </section>
```

Lo que quiero es que al alguien ganar la partida no se pueda hacer click en los cuadros restantes
la funcion verificarGanador devuelve X o O si alguien gano y si no devuelve null

```
const cuadros = document.querySelectorAll('.cuadro');
const Resultado = document.getElementById('Resultado');

const puntajeX = document.getElementById('puntajeX');
const puntajeO = document.getElementById('puntajeO');

console.log(cuadros);
var turno = "X";
var jugadas = 0;
var tablero = [];
var puntoX = 0;
var puntoO = 0;

const siguiente = document.getElementById('siguiente');

for (var i = 0; i < cuadros.length; i++) {
    
    cuadros[i].addEventListener('click',crearManejador(i));
    
}

function crearManejador(indice) {
    return function() {
        if(cuadros[indice].textContent  === ""){
            if(turno == "X"){
                cuadros[indice].textContent = "X";
                
                tablero[indice] = "X"
                turno = "O";
                jugadas++;
               
            }else if(turno == "O"){
                cuadros[indice].textContent = "O";
                
                turno = "X";
                tablero[indice] = "O"
                jugadas++;   
            }
        }else{
            return;
        }

       
        if( verificarGanador(tablero) != null){
            Resultado.innerHTML = `Ha ganado el equipo: ${verificarGanador(tablero)}`;
            for (var i = 0; i < cuadros.length; i++) {
                
                cuadros[i].removeEventListener('click', crearManejador(i));
                //al terminar la partida quiero que no se pueda seguir marcando los cuadros restantes 
                
                
            }
            //
            if(verificarGanador(tablero) == "X"){
                puntoX++;
                puntajeX.innerHTML=puntoX;
            }else{
                puntoO++;
                puntajeO.innerHTML=puntoO;
            }
            tablero = [];
            siguiente.classList.add('mostrar');
        }else if( jugadas > 8 ){
            Resultado.innerHTML = "Empate";
            tablero = []
            siguiente.classList.add('mostrar');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No se elimina evento con Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600527/no-se-elimina-evento-con-javascript)

Comment: Hola. No se entiende muy bien qué es lo que quieres hacer, ni el contexto. Parece que intentas agregar y remover los listeners sin más. ¿Qué sentido tendría eso en un escenario real? Otra cosa sería: *quiero remover el listener luego de que se haga click una vez en ese elemento*  o *una vez se haga click `N` veces en ese elemento*, o *si el valor de ese elemento fuese tal o esté en blanco....*, etc. Pulsa en [edit] y aclara tu problema agregando información contextual que nos ayude a comprender mejor.